# jQuery .eq() only works on first row in table

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I try to redirect user to the other page but if he/she clicks 5, 8 or last cell in table, nothing will be happen. It's ok for first row. But the other rows not working.

```
$("#table td:not(:last-child,:eq(5),:eq(8))").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).parent().find('td:last-child a[title="edit"]').attr('href');          
        if (url != undefined) {
            location.href = $(this).parent().find('td:last-child a[title="edit"]').attr('href');
        }
    });
```

Comment: :eq selects by index within collection, not index within parent. Try :nth-child()

Comment: Maybe you should use classes instead of line 5 and 8.

Comment: @KevinB So how can I affect all rows separately

Comment: @jantimon please tell me more. What you mean ?

Comment: @YasinYörük You should just give 'em all separate classes and assign your handler to them. It's a lot easier to maintain should your rows change... Is probably what he means.

Comment: use `#table td:not(:last-child,:nth-child(5),:nth-child(8))`

Comment: @YasinYörük by replace :eq with :nth-child, keep in mind though it isn't a 1:1 replacement.

Comment: @DavidFregoli it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use delegation

```
$("#table").on('click', 'td', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.index() === 4 || $this.index() === 7 || $this.is(':last-child') ) return;
    var url = $this.nextAll('td:last-child a[title="edit"]').attr('href');          
    if (url != undefined) {
        location.href = $this.nextAll('td:last-child a[title="edit"]').attr('href');
    }
    return false
});
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much. But just I change the index numbers in if statement. 4 to 5 and 7 to 8.